# Polynomial that interpolate the function f at points using java

Tags: java, math, interpolation

I have the values

```
x = 0   =>   y = 0
x = 1   =>   y = 1
x = 3   =>   y = 27
x = 4   =>   y = 64
```

I want to create a polynomial function using JAVA to create the function x^3. The program should create the function and display it, and if i give any values it should calculate the interpolated values. I have created a function which just produced the values using Aitken but it doesnt produce the function and it is really hard to understand how to do the function. Because i dont know how to put the X value as X in the java program.

Comment: "I have created a function which just produced the values..." -- What does this mean?  Does this mean you have coefficients?  "The program should create the function and display it."  -- What does this mean?  That your program needs to graph it?

Comment: No, what i need is the function x^3 produced by the java function. So the output of the program would be x^3

Comment: Input of my program will be double xi[] = {-15,0,15,30,}; double fi[] = {-0.24913878, 0,0.221456693,0.415231299}; any array. So the program should produce the associated polynomial function.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with you, and finally got the solution.
Just look at Apache commons math API. You can use both Lagrange's or Newton's method to compute the coefficient of each polynomial degree.

You can download the .jar file of the API [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-math/2.1), and the documentations [here](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 4 pairs of (x,y) points. Consider the equation a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 = y. Put the 4 pairs of (x,y) and you have 4 linear equations in 4 variables. Use a matrix solver or write your own to solve for (a0...a3). Now you can have a methode interpolate(double x) { return a0*x+a1*x*x+a2*x^2+a3*x^3; }. Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually want to create the function. input of my program would be 2 arrays, x[]={0,1,2,3} and y[]={0,1,8,27}...the output which i want is x^3 ....the program should find out the function for me....there are 2 methods, newtons and lagrange methode. but its hard to code it because i dun know how to put the x value in the program as x itself.

Comment: Can you share the psuedocode for what you are trying to implement? After you have the coefficients, do you want to print out the function, or use them in some other method to interpolate for y for a given x?

Comment: the psuedocode is public static double aitkenInterpolation(double x) {
 double xi[] = {-15, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60};
 double fi[] = {-0.24913878, 0, 0.221456693, 0.415231299, 0.581323819, 0.719734252};
 int n = xi.length-1;
    double ft[] = (double[]) fi.clone();
    for (int i=2; i<3; ++i) {
      for (int j=2; j<3; ++j) {
     ft[j] = (x-xi[j])/(xi[i+j+1]-xi[j])*ft[j+1]+(x-xi[i+j+1])/(xi[j]-xi[i+j+1])*ft[j];
      }
    }
    return ft[0];
  }  . This gives me the interpolated values, but what i need is the function come out as an output too..

Answer (score 0):

I have the values x = 0 => y = 0 x = 1 => y = 1 x = 2 => y = 27 x = 3 => y = 64

This is an odd way to list points.

Too bad that they aren't part of y = x^3.  These are:

(x, y) = { (0,0), (1,1), (2, 8), (3, 27), (4, 64), (5, 125)...}

UPDATE:

I'd word your question differently.  Your "example" set of points is incorrect and misleading.  It sounds like you're really saying "I have an arbitrary set of points and I'd like to fit a function to them."

If you know the form of the funcion you need, the problem is merely about calculating the unknown coefficients.  If you have as many points as coefficients you can solve for them (if a solution exists).  If you have more points than coefficients you can do least squares fitting.

But all this depends on knowing what function you want beforehand.

Asking a computer to ferret out both  the best form and the coefficient values for you is a daunting task.

You can certainly use Lagrange interpolation between points, but it still may not be the thing to tell you what the "best" function is to represent your points.  It assumes polynomial forms, so mixing in other functions isn't part of the method.  It could give you a very nice representation for sin(x), but it won't come out and tell you that a sine function would be easier to understand than a polynomial approximation.

Comment: Maybe he wants to find a degree-three polynomial that fits the points he gave.

Comment: exactly, i just given an example here...what i need is, i give 2 array as input for example double [\n] xi[] = {-15, 0, 15, 30}; double fi[] = {-0.24913878, 0, 0.221456693, 0.415231299};. The java program should produce the interpolated function for that.

Comment: I want to implement this using lagrange method or newtons method. I managed to get the interpolated values using the following source code..But it doesnt give me the function. What should I do inorder to get the function?

Comment: public static double aitkenInterpolation(double x) {
 double xi[] = {-15, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60};
 double fi[] = {-0.24913878, 0, 0.221456693, 0.415231299, 0.581323819, 0.719734252};
 int n = xi.length-1;
    double ft[] = (double[]) fi.clone();
    for (int i=2; i<3; ++i) {
      for (int j=2; j<3; ++j) {
     ft[j] = (x-xi[j])/(xi[i+j+1]-xi[j])*ft[j+1]+(x-xi[i+j+1])/(xi[j]-xi[i+j+1])*ft[j];
      }
    }
    return ft[0];
  }

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment.